# Classic Vuex to Modular: Why is Getter now undefined?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, vuexfire

I am moving from classic vuex to modular vuex, but i need some help understanding how to call getters in my app. Here's what I have in store:

> `store/user.js`:

```
export const state = () => ({
  currentUser: null,
  userProfile: {}
})
export const getters = {
  loggedIn(state) {
    return !!state.currentUser
  }
}
```

When I call `loggedIn` from my app, I get `loggedIn` as `undefined`.  Here's how I am calling `loggedIn`:

> `src/components/MainNav.vue`:

```
computed: {    
loggedIn() {
      return this.$store.getters.user.loggedIn
    }
}
```

Anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: so  I had to add `mapGetters` to my code and it works now. I'll update my answer accordingly...but perhaps others have better ways to approach this thank.

Comment: Why do you use user between getters and loggedIn ? do you have multiple stores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your store has the `user` namespace, so you have to call your `loggedIn` getter as below:

```js
computed: {    
  loggedIn() {
    return this.$store.getters['user/loggedIn']
  }
}
```

Another way is to use the `mapGetter` helper, as explains in [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing)